# .h and .m files for view controllers added within storyboard xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, xcode4

I've created the flow of my application with storyboard.  It's a navigation based storyboard layout with a few stacks of views.  Where can I create .h and .m files to actually make the app DO things?  The general navigational flow of the app is just fine as a result of story board, but I need to add my own code to the views.  Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Go to File->New->New File and create a UIViewSubclass without the xib/nib for each view that you have. This will create the .h and .m files. Then, select the view in the storyboard and go to Identity Inspector in the right column view. Under Custom Class->Class, select the new UIViewSubclass (by name) that you just created. This will link the view with the header and implementation files.

Comment: What if you want to assign a delegate (controller) that's defined in a separate m file to a subview?