# storyboard attach view to code xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5.1

I've read here about how to do what I want to do in Xcode 4, but in Xcode 5.1 there is no UIViewSubclass. I can only find Objective C class and View. Am I missing something simple?

[.h and .m files for view controllers added within storyboard xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8707670/h-and-m-files-for-view-controllers-added-within-storyboard-xcode-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new file choose "Objective-C Class". Then, below the field "Class" there is a field called "Subclass of". Just type in UIView, and it would become the subclass of UIView.

You can find similar steps in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708936/how-to-create-new-view-controllers-in-xcode-4-3)